# Detecting hyperlinks in a PDF file

Tags: ruby, pdf, ghostscript, prawn, pdf-reader

We're using [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn)'s templating functionality to add content to PDF files. However, this breaks hyperlinks in the PDF files used as templates, as documented in "[Prawn corrupts links in template file #503](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/503)".

We'd like to be able to warn our users that their hyperlinks will be broken, but we can't figure out how to detect whether the file has hyperlinks or not.

Is it possible to do this using Prawn, Ghostscript, or something else that could run on a Heroku Ruby instance?

Comment: While we'd like to help, it's off-topic on Stack Overflow to request suggestions to off-site resources such as you're asking for. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @theTinMan re-worded the question- thanks

Comment: Nicely reworded. We're working on reopening it.

Comment: Ghostscript isn't specifically intended to detect hyperlinks, but these are always annotations outside the body of the contents, so it is possible to detect them. You would have to modify the PDF interpreter. You don't say if by 'hyperlinks' you mean links to locations inside the document or to locations external to the document. The two are different, one is a URI and the other is a Link.